# Discord.js(v13) - Delete a channel with discord button

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I made a discord selection menu ticket that when I select that category it makes a channel and send a message with a button. The button is supposed to delete the channel when pressed, but it doesn't seem to work. I think I have found the error but I don't know how to fix it. It is probably easy to fix but I'm stuck.

The code: (I think the error is located in the end here)

```
 } else if (Discord.MessageButton.customId === 'del') {
 const channel = message.guild.channel
            channel.delete();
```

---

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { MessageSelectMenu, MessageActionRow } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {

    name: "ticket",
    author: "Falcone",

    run: async(client, message, args) => {

        if (!message.member.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply('You Dont Have the `ADMINISTRATOR` permision');

        message.delete();

        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .setDescription(`Test`)
        .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }));


        let painel = new MessageActionRow().addComponents( new MessageSelectMenu()
        .setCustomId('menu')
        .setPlaceholder('Test') // Mensagem estampada
        .addOptions([
               {
                    label: 'Support',
                    description: '',
                    emoji: '‍♂️',
                    value: '1',
               },
               {
                label: 'Test',
                description: '',
                emoji: '⛔',
                value: '2',
               },
               {
                label: 'Test',
                description: '',
                emoji: '',
                value: '3',
               }
            ])

        );


        message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [painel] }).then(msg => {


            const filtro = (interaction) => 
            interaction.isSelectMenu()

      
          const coletor = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
            filtro
          });
      

          coletor.on('collect', async (collected) => {

            let ticket = collected.values[0]
            collected.deferUpdate()



           
        
            if (ticket === "1") {

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Ticket')
                .setDescription('Hello there, \n The staff will be here as soon as possible mean while tell us about your issue!\nThank You!')
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setTimestamp()

            const del = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new Discord.MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('del')
                    .setLabel('️ Delete Ticket!')
                    .setStyle('DANGER'),
                );

                message.guild.channels.create(`${collected.user.id}`, {
                    type : 'GUILD_TEXT',
                    permissionOverwrites : [
                        {
                            id : message.guild.id,
                            deny : ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                        },
                        {
                            id : collected.user.id,
                            allow : ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES', 'ATTACH_FILES']
                        }
                    ]
                }).then(async (msg) => {
        
                    msg.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [del] }).then(msg => msg.pin() );
                
                })
            } else if (Discord.MessageButton.customId === 'del') {

                const channel = message.guild.channel
                channel.delete();
    
            }
 

        })


        });

        

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: it doesnt say anything @MrMythical

Answer (score 0):

`MessageButton.customId` is not a static property. That means it must be done on an instance, not the class. Something that you could try is this:

```js
const msg = await message.channel.send({
  content: "Which one?",
  components: [
    new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents([
      new Discord.MessageButton().setLabel("Delete").setStyle("DANGER").setCustomId("DEL"), //delete button
      new Discord.MessageButton().setLabel("Cancel").setStyle("DANGER").setCustomId("CAN") //cancel button
    ])
  ]
})

//Create button collector
const collector = msg.createMessageComponentCollector({
  componentType: "BUTTON",
  filter: (c) => c.member.id === msg.member.id,
  max: 1
})


//Handle button click
collector.on("collect", i => {
  if(i.customId === "CAN") return i.reply("Cancelled")
  if(i.customId === "DEL") i.channel.delete() //or whatever channel you want to delete
})
```

<sup>Warning: I did not test this code. You can tell me any problems you have and I will try to modify this</sup>

Comment: can you edit your code in mine cause im not sure if i added it correctly. Because it says `content must not be an empty string`

Comment: Can you send the code? It can be an image

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/761592302916993055/897939930297303040/Screenshot_2021-10-13_231219.png

Comment: Switch it from `content: embed` to `embeds: [embed]`

Comment: ok i did and now it works but it sends the embed in the same channel and the buttons dont work